# How to authenticate basic Java program for Github API

Tags: java, authentication, github, https

I'm trying to create a basic Java app that access's the Github API and collects information. I need to be able to perform more than 60 requests per hour but have no idea how to authorize my app. The app is not public and doesn't require user authentication just access to more than 60 requests per hour.

My code so far:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.github.com/users/"+name);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            String response = con.getResponseMessage();
            if(responseCode == 200){
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String content = reader.readLine();
                System.out.print(name + " - " + responseCode + " - " + response + " - " + content + "\n");
            }else{
                System.out.print(name + " - " + responseCode + " - " + response + "\n");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I believe it can be done by adding another header/requestProperty, but am unsure how.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Checked this : https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/ ?

Comment: Yeah, I can't make sense of it for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works well for me:

```
    package com.test.api.api;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;

    public class GitHub {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(
            "Your Email ID here", "Your Password");
    clientConfig.register(feature);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://api.github.com").path(
            "authorizations");

    String input = "{\"scopes\":[\"public_repo\"],\"note\":\"Ramanuj\"}";

    Response response = webTarget.request("application/json").post(
            Entity.json(input));
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));

        }
    }
```

You need to have following dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This code will print token in your console so you can use it in follow-on requests to github.com

This is equivalent to OAuth 2 Authorization.

Comment: If you want to know what I am posting then check here -> https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization